# Insert Foreign Records using IDs from Insert Into Query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My goal is to split each row from the 'Book' table (if it has a non-null publish_date) into two 'Book' rows, the original row and a new row with a new auto-incremented id, a new publish_type, no publish_date (not relevent) and the same isbn.

I wrote a SQL statement to do this, but the trick is that now, I need to take each new row's id and create new foreign records in the 'Origin' table based off of each original Book's Origin record - I basically need to duplicate the Origin records so each new Book record maps to the correct (original's) country_codes in the Origin table.

```
/* Here are the tables */
Book
id | publish_date | publish_type | isbn

Origin
customer id | country_code

Country
id | country_code

/* First query to split book objects into two */
INSERT INTO Book (id, publish_date, publish_type, isbn)
SELECT NULL, 'Published', isbn
FROM Book
WHERE publish_date IS NOT NULL;
```

e.g..

```
/* Before */
Book
id | publish_date | publish_type | isbn
1  | 1/1/2000     |              | 123
2  |              |              | 456
3  | 2/2/2002     |              | 789

Origin
customer id | country_code
1           | US
1           | AR
2           | BR
3           | MX

Country
id | country_code
5  | US
6  | AR
7  | BR
8  | MX
```

---

```
/* After */
Book
id | publish_date | publish_type | isbn
1  | 1/1/2000     |              | 123
2  |              |              | 456
3  | 2/2/2002     |              | 789
4  |              |  Published   | 123
5  |              |  Published   | 789

Origin
customer id | country_code
1           | US
1           | AR
2           | BR
3           | MX
4           | US
4           | AR
5           | MX

Country
id | country_code
5  | US
6  | AR
7  | BR
8  | MX
```

It seems like I need some kind of subquery or insert into select from statement that can use the previous query's ids to copy over the foreign origin records related to the original book row's keys, but I'm having trouble identifying how to carry over the input.

Comment: Duplicating customers and countries because you modify a book sounds wrong.

Comment: You're absolutely right, customer_id was actually supposed to be book_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use CTEs.  The trick is to use the ISBN to get the original `origin` information:

```
with b as (
      INSERT INTO Book (publish_date, publish_type, isbn)
          SELECT NULL, 'Published', isbn
          FROM Book
          WHERE publish_date IS NOT NULL
          RETURNING *
     )
insert into origin (customer_id, country_code)
    select b.id, o.country_code
    from origin o join
         book
         on o.customer_id = book.id join
         b
         on b.isbn = book.isbn and publish_date is null;
```

Comment: This was the exact structure I needed, the WITH AS and RETURNING * pattern. All I needed to do was tweak the criteria at the end and it worked, thank you!